# How to change the default 404 page while using python SimpleHTTPServer

Tags: python, simplehttpserver

When I start a http server using a command:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

How can i change the default 404 page?

Comment: If you're planning on making a web application, don't use SimpleHTTPServer. It's slow, single-threaded, and unstable under any sort of load.

Answer (score 4):

With command line, it is impossible.

You should make a script like following:

```
import BaseHTTPServer
import SimpleHTTPServer

class MyHandler(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    error_message_format = '''
    custom error message
    '''

BaseHTTPServer.test(MyHandler, BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer)
```